# How to find the location of the Scheduled Tasks folder

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have seen references online that state that 'Scheduled Tasks' in Windows are stored in `%SystemRoot%\Tasks`, which I think usually equates to `C:\Windows\Tasks`.

However, I observe that while that folder exists on my Windows 7 system, Scheduled tasks doesn't use it.

My system appears to use, `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`.

I have studied the Environment variables and there doesn't seem to be anything related to `Scheduled Tasks` there.

How do I discover which folder is used for Scheduled tasks?

Comment: In python you might be able to use the ctypes module ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216173/how-to-get-path-of-start-menus-programs-directory)). However I couldn't find a reference to sheduled tasks specifically.

Comment: You don't normally operate on the folder itself since that's private to windows. The way to automate control of tasks is through the api.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Totally agree, but there are moments when you need to. Today I messed up the SDDL of one of my tasks. Was unable to fix this using the api before I found the tasks under \System32\Tasks. Very helpful question. +1

Answer (score 72):

## Tasks are saved in filesystem AND registry

Tasks are stored in 3 locations: 1 file system location and 2 registry locations.

#### File system:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Tasks
```

#### Registry:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache\Tasks
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache\Tree
```

So, you need to delete a corrupted task in these 3 locations.

Comment: The registry Taskcache really helped me, thanks! I had a backup of the whole registry of my old Windows install, while the tasks themselves were already gone (with the Windows).

Comment: Thanks alot, this solved my problem. Surprisingly many google links do show non working solutions not mentioning the hidden folder in the file system

Comment: There are also tasks in `%SystemRoot%\Tasks` (`C:\Windows\Tasks`), which under certain conditions don't show up in the Task Scheduler snap-in.

Answer (score 14):

I want to extend @Jan answer:

It's seems, that `Task Scheduler 1.0 API` uses `C:\Windows\Tasks` folder for create and enumerate tasks ([this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446831(v=vs.85).aspx)), while `Task Scheduler 2.0 API` uses `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` to create and enumerate tasks ([this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa446864(v=vs.85).aspx)).

It's also seems, that windows console utility `schtasks` and GUI utility `taskschd.msc` uses `Task Scheduler 2.0 API`.

P.S.
I found, that if task placed in `C:\Windows\Tasks` and *have not* set `AccountInformation`, then task *won't be displayed* in windows console and GUI schedulers. If you *set* `AccountInformation` (even "" for SYSTEM account) and *set* flag `TASK_FLAG_RUN_ONLY_IF_LOGGED_ON` - task *will be* displayed in all standard applications.

[Solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774644/trying-to-create-a-scheduled-task-to-run-once-using-c-task-scheduler-1-0-on)

Answer (score 8):

For Windows 7 and up, scheduled tasks are not run by `cmd.exe`, but rather by `MMC` (Microsoft Management Console). `%SystemRoot%\Tasks` should work on any other Windows version though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like TaskCache registry data is in ...

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache`

... on my Windows 10 PC (i.e. add **Schedule** before **TaskCache** and Task**C**ache has an upper case **C**).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the MMC however as on almost every PC in my business the ask scheduler API will not open and has somehow been corrupted.  So you cannot edit, delete or otherwise modify tasks that were developed before the API decided not to run anymore. The only way we have found to fix that issue is to totally wipe away a persons profile under the C:\Users\ area and force the system to recreate the log in once the person logs back in.  This seems to fix the API issue and it works again, however the tasks are often not visible anymore to that user since the tasks developed are specific to the user and not the machine in Windows 7.  The other odd thing is that sometimes, although not with any frequency that can be analyzed, the tasks still run even though the API is corrupted and will not open.  The cause of this issue is apparently not known but there are many "fixes" described on various websites, but the user profile deletion and adding anew seems to work every time for at least a little while.  The tasks are saved as XML now in WIN 7, so if you do find them in the system32/tasks folder you can delete them, or copy them to a new drive and then import them back into task scheduler.  We went with the system scheduler software  from Splinterware though since we had the same corruption issue multiple times even with the fix that does not seem to be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of Windows (Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016) the tasks you create are located in `C:\Windows\Tasks`.  They will have the extension `.job`

For example if you create the task "DoWork" it will create the task in

```
C:\Windows\Tasks\DoWork.job
```

Comment: In my Windows Server 2016 instance tasks are located in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\` and they are XML files with no extension.

Comment: in Windows 11 22H2 they are also still saved in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`