Adding task using Interface 1.0 Win32 API doesn't show up in the Task schedular GUI
I was trying to run the sample program, taken from the Microsoft docs. Seems the is being created (.job file found in the C:\Windows\Tasks) but it is not listed on Task schedular GUI.
Is this related to interface 1.0?
EDIT:
In addition to the sample program added TASK_FLAG_RUN_ONLY_IF_LOGGED_ON flag and set the account using SetAccountInformation.
void stringError(HRESULT hr) {
    _com_error err(hr);
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error (%ls) : ", errMsg);
}

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        stringError(hr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize COM library, error = 0x%x\n", hr);
        return 1;
    }

    ITaskScheduler* pITS = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CTaskScheduler, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskScheduler, (void**)&pITS);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        stringError(hr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create Task Scheduler instance, error = 0x%x\n", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    LPCWSTR pwszTaskName = L"SampleTask";
    ITask* pITask = NULL;
    IPersistFile* pIPersistFile = NULL;

    hr = pITS->NewWorkItem(pwszTaskName, CLSID_CTask, IID_ITask, (IUnknown**)&pITask);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (hr == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_EXISTS))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Task already exists. Attempting to delete...\n");
            hr = pITS->Delete(pwszTaskName);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                stringError(hr);
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to delete existing task, error = 0x%x\n", hr);
                pITS->Release();
                CoUninitialize();
                return 1;
            }

            hr = pITS->NewWorkItem(pwszTaskName, CLSID_CTask, IID_ITask, (IUnknown**)&pITask);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                stringError(hr);
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create new task after deletion, error = 0x%x\n", hr);
                pITS->Release();
                CoUninitialize();
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stringError(hr);
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create new task, error = 0x%x\n", hr);
            pITS->Release();
            CoUninitialize();
            return 1;
        }
    }   

    pITS->Release();

    hr = pITask->SetFlags(TASK_FLAG_RUN_ONLY_IF_LOGGED_ON);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        stringError(hr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set task flags, error = 0x%x\n", hr);
        pITask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pITask->SetAccountInformation(L"", NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        stringError(hr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set account information, error = 0x%x\n", hr);
        pITask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pITask->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&pIPersistFile);
    pITask->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        stringError(hr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to query IPersistFile interface, error = 0x%x\n", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pIPersistFile->Save(NULL, TRUE);
    pIPersistFile->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        stringError(hr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to save the task, error = 0x%x\n", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    printf("Task created successfully.\n");
    return 0;
}

Issue: Unable to save the task. Prints the following error - (The task XML contains an unexpected node.) : Failed to save the task, error = 0x80041316.

Task Scheduler 1.0 API uses C:\Windows\Tasks folder to create and enumerate tasks.
Task Scheduler 2.0 API uses C:\Windows\System32\Tasks folder to create and enumerate tasks.
It is the reason that the task is not listed on Task schedular GUI.
If you want to use Task Scheduler 1.0 API to create tasks and show the task on Task schedular GUI, you could try to set flag TASK_FLAG_RUN_ONLY_IF_LOGGED_ON and set AccountInformation.
For more details, you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9782931

Added the changes, now While performing save, it fails with - 0x80041316 : The task XML contains an unexpected node. I tried to set the account info with local Systems i.e. Username = L"" and the password to be NULL.

What version of Windows are you using? According to the Doc:IScheduledWorkItem::SetAccountInformation method This API may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of the operating system or product.
I suggest you could use the Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces instead.

Before the changes done that is setting up account info and flag. Was able to run without any error.  So guessing the issue is not with the OS. I use windows 11.

I tested the official sample: set Task Account Information and I could reproduce the issue. It seems an issue. I suggest you could post feedback.
And I still suggest you use the Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces instead.
