# where is my batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I made several bat files using task scheduler(custom) and I need to apply these to all of my 70 server computers. Obviously I don't want to repeat the same procedure at every server.

Can I simply copy and paste my bat files to different computers and expect same result?

If so, where are my bat files and where should I paste them?

Comment: My Task Scheduler on windows 10 requires me to browse to the file location after selecting when I want the task to start. That's how I find my files

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy your batch files to different servers.
This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913816/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-scheduled-tasks-folder) shows location of task scheduler.

---

### Folder location:

```
%systemroot%\System32\Tasks
```

### Registry:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache\Tasks
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache\Tree
```

You may want to try the `xcopy` and `for` command to send your batch file to all servers.

### Command syntax:

`FOR` command can loop through your server names, and `XCOPY` copys the batch script to the other servers.

```
for %%G in (serverA
            serverB
            serverC
            ...
            serverZ) do xcopy [source] [destination] [options]
```

Note that asterisks does not work as intended, since it works as a wildcard.