# How can I create a scheduled task using PowerShell that runs every x minutes or x hours?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, windows-11, powershell-7.3

Using PowerShell 7.3.1, so can't use `Register-ScheduledJob`. without having to directly modify scheduled task XML files, since they are [stored in 3 different places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913816/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-scheduled-tasks-folder), how can I create a scheduled task in Windows that runs every x hours or x minutes.

I've done this in GUI

[image]

and I want to do something like that in PowerShell.

I've checked out [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1373275/how-to-schedule-a-task-with-powershell-to-run-every-hour-monday-to-friday-betwe), but it's incomplete for my situation.

Reading `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=windowsserver2022-ps), can't seem to find a parameter for each of them.

this is all I could figure out

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -RepetitionInterval "PT5M"
```

**another idea**, if it's actually impossible to do what I want with native PowerShell, what if I create my task with PowerShell and a placeholder trigger like `at startup`, then use `schtasks.exe` to configure the trigger according to the screenshot I uploaded?

if that's doable, what are the command(s) for using `schtasks.exe` to modify the trigger like in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass [`[timespan]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) instances to the relevant parameters of the [`New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger) cmdlet, which you can construct with the [`New-TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan) cmdlet, for instance.

```bash
$trigger = 
  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger `
    -Once -At (Get-Date).AddSeconds(5) `
    -RandomDelay (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 30) `
    -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5)
```

Note:

- `-Once -At (Get-Date).AddSeconds(5)` starts the task *once*, *5 seconds from now*.

  - `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` seemingly offers *no* way to specify the "At task creation / modification" option shown in your screenshot (the only non-time-related options are `-AtLogon` and `-AtStartup`, the latter referring to the *system*'s startup), and it is imperative that the `-At` value *lie in the future* for the task to actually start, *hence the 5-second delay* - this isn't foolproof, but unless your system is under exceptionally heavy load, this should do.
- `-At` expects a [`[datetime]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instance, and [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) without arguments returns the current point in time.

Comment: Thank you, how can I define the `at` for `at task creation/modification` ? because it asks me for it. `cmdlet New-ScheduledTaskTrigger at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
At:` .

Comment: Thanks again for the updated answer, perfect as always! I was reading the DateTime struct to supply it with a DateTime type variable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0 because I just noticed that in Microsoft docs they say what the type of each parameter should be and I wasn't paying attention to that or rather was having a hard time finding a reference to those types.

Comment: My pleasure, @Jameschad; I've added the `-Once` and `-At` arguments, and `-At` comes with a pitfall - please see my update.