# Python locate "all programs" folder in the start menu

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, shortcut

I'm trying to create a folder with shortcuts in it inside the windows folder "Programs" in the start menu. I've already found a way of creating shorkuts but I can't find a way to locate the "programs" folder in the start menu. For example to find the desktop folder I use:

```
os.environ["userprofile"]+"\\Desktop\\"
```

but I want it with "programs" folder with the programs folder.

Note: I'm not searching for the "Program Files" Folder!!! I'm searching for the folder in the start menu "Programs", that for example in my computer is in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"

Comment: I Found a solution!! "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" in the registry

Comment: a solution using `ctypes` module is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216173/how-to-get-path-of-start-menus-programs-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, in the registry, there is a key named "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" that has the desktop, programs, start menu etc. I will be able to acces it with the _winreg module.

Answer (score 2):

This does it for me:

```
os.path.join(os.environ["userprofile"], "Start Menu", "Programs")
```

There's probably a more proper way to do it with the Windows API, but I don't know it.

Edit:

Here are a couple related materials for the Windows API that might help. I don't know the Windows API well enough to make a script for you, though.

- [How do I find the Windows common application data folder using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626796/how-do-i-find-the-windows-common-application-data-folder-using-python)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181.aspx

Comment: Nope, for me, that folder doesn't exist... That's a problem, there should be a proper way... maybe in the registry or something like that...

Comment: In case you're willing to try out the Windows API in Python, see my answer again.

Comment: I found a solution, in the registry, there is a key named "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" that hast the desktop, programs, start menu etc. I will be able to acces it with the _winreg module.

Comment: That's good! If it really works, you can actually post that as an answer to your own question instead of a comment, and accept that answer.