# How to get Windows' special folders for currently logged-in user?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

How can I get Windows special folders like `My Documents`, `Desktop`, etc. from my Python script? Do I need win32 extensions?

It must work on Windows 2000 to Windows 7.

Comment: related: [Find system folder locations in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2063508/4279)

Comment: List of windows folder constants: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do it with the pywin32 extensions:

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
print shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_MYPICTURES, None, 0)
# prints something like C:\Documents and Settings\Username\My Documents\My Pictures
# (Unicode object)
```

Check `shellcon.CSIDL_xxx` for other possible folders.

I think using pywin32 is the best way. Else you'd have to use `ctypes` to access the `SHGetFolderPath` function somehow (other solutions might be possible but these are the ones I know).

Comment: Thanks! 
What exactly is shell in windows and what is shellcon ?

Comment: @Primoz: I don't know what the abbreviations mean, but all *con modules in the pywin32 package are autogenerated from Windows header files and only contain definitions. The `win32com.shell` module contains functions from shell32.dll.

Comment: The docs mention constants `SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT` and `SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT` for the last parameter of `SHGetFolderPath()`, but these aren't defined in `shellcon` for some reason... I wonder why not.

Comment: Note that not all shellcon.CSIDL_xxx values are valid on all machines.  For example on my machine CSIDL_PERSONAL (5) is valid but CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS (12) is not. http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/06/08/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-query-the-contents-of-a-special-folder-on-a-windows-7-computer.aspx has a great powershell script for listing all of the special values on a particular machine.

Comment: note that My Documents is not retrievable this way. You need to use: `df = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()  
pidl = df.ParseDisplayName(0, None, "::{450d8fba-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}")[1]  
mydocs = shell.SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl)`

Comment: Can I get reverse functionality. Like I have path as "C:\Windows\dir1\dir2\xyz.dll" and I want to get output as "csidl_windows\dir1\dir2\xyz.dll"?

Comment: You can do prefix matching against CSIDL's that you want to check, but there's no direct way to reverse it. I also wouldn't know any use case for it.

Comment: @AndiDog, what is the benefit of this approach over using ctypes?

Comment: `ctypes` isn't easy to get right. Luckily someone provided a correct (I guess) answer, but manually writing calls to lots of C functions and getting the data right can be non-trivial. No huge difference otherwise and actually ctypes usage will remove one required dependency.

Answer (score 25):

Should you wish to do it without the win32 extensions, you can use `ctypes` to call [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
>>> import ctypes.wintypes
>>> CSIDL_PERSONAL= 5       # My Documents
>>> SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT= 0   # Want current, not default value

>>> buf= ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(ctypes.wintypes.MAX_PATH)
>>> ctypes.windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW(0, CSIDL_PERSONAL, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, buf)
0
>>> buf.value
u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\User\\My Documents'
```

Comment: Your code (also) illustrates one of the limitations of using `ctypes` instead of the `win32` extensions, namely the fact that the former doesn't supply any of the often needed Window's constants like those defined in `win32com.shellcon` -- so one has to look-up their values and add each of them manually.

Comment: Nice solution. And working on my Windows 8. However, the MS Doc (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28VS.85%29.aspx) says that it's `deprecated`. I'm not sure what are the implications...

Comment: THANKS A LOT. BTW constant values are here: http://www.installmate.com/support/im9/using/symbols/functions/csidls.htm

Comment: By the way, I had to do `ctypes.windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW(0, CSIDL_PERSONAL, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, buf)` twice. The first time I got error code `-2147024890`.

Comment: Regarding `deprecated`: The SHGetKnownFolderPath is [much more cumbersome](https://gist.github.com/mkropat/7550097) to use, so I would use win32com in that case. Using the answer here for now, to keep down my dependencies :).

Comment: @thomasa88: indeed! And, as `SHGetFolderPathW()`  is already a wrapper to `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` since Windows Vista, this will possibly be available in the foreseeable future, deprecated or not...

Answer (score 9):

```
import win32com.client
oShell = win32com.client.Dispatch("Wscript.Shell")
print oShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
```

Answer (score 6):

Try [winshell](https://winshell.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (made exactly for this purpose):

```
import winshell

print 'Desktop =>', winshell.desktop ()
print 'Common Desktop =>', winshell.desktop (1)
print 'Application Data =>', winshell.application_data ()
print 'Common Application Data =>', winshell.application_data (1)
print 'Bookmarks =>', winshell.bookmarks ()
print 'Common Bookmarks =>', winshell.bookmarks (1)
print 'Start Menu =>', winshell.start_menu ()
print 'Common Start Menu =>', winshell.start_menu (1)
print 'Programs =>', winshell.programs ()
print 'Common Programs =>', winshell.programs (1)
print 'Startup =>', winshell.startup ()
print 'Common Startup =>', winshell.startup (1)
print 'My Documents =>', winshell.my_documents ()
print 'Recent =>', winshell.recent ()
print 'SendTo =>', winshell.sendto ()
```

Comment: It's just a wrapper around pywin32, and if I need pywin32, I rather used it without another layer.

Comment: Ridiculously simple and straightforward--and therefore beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit hacky, but without the need of a special import

```
import os
os.popen('echo %appdata%').read().strip()
```

Comment: Why not use `os.environ`?

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/userpaths is an alternatve for that.

```
# Get the user's My Documents folder
import userpaths
my_docs = userpaths.get_my_documents()
```

You can directly use like that.