# screen-shots in ubuntu versus windows through python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take a screenshot via a python script. [Linux]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux)

How can I achieve the capturing screen-shots and saving in a folder as achieved by the following python code in windows in linux (ubuntu)? I also want to run it at the OS start-up.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import Image
import ImageGrab
SaveDirectory=r'C:\Documents and Settings\gg\Desktop\office_docs'
```

## ---------------------------------------------------------

```
for i in range(10000):

img=ImageGrab.grab()
saveas=os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'ScreenShot_'+time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')+'.png')
img.save(saveas)
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do, is replace the path of SaveDirectory with a path that works on both operating systems.

Based on [How to get the home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python), you can use [os.path.expanduser](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.expanduser) to replace ~ with your home directory.

A possible solution is:

```
from os.path import expanduser
import os.path.join

SaveDirectory = expanduser(os.path.join('Desktop', 'office_docs'))
```

For the second part of the question, it depends whether you want to do it via a GUI or manually editing a config file. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup) you should find the instruction for the GUI. [Here](http://rednectar.net/2010/11/04/changing-ubuntu-gnome-startup-applications/) you can find the instructions for the config file way.

I should note that [the python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) suggest lowercase names with words separated by underscores for instance variables since it improves readability, but this is just a suggestion.

I hope you find this answer useful and apologise if it does not work as I have not tested it myself.

Comment: to get path for Desktop reliably on Windows see [Python, get windows special folders for currently logged-in user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3858851/4279)