# Trying to figure out mixed results of call to win32com.client.Dispatch

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5169864/2065006

So I thought I would experiment.  Can someone with a little more experience explain these result?

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> shellobject = win32com.client.Dispatch("Wscript.Shell")
>>> print (shellobject.SpecialFolders("ProgramFiles"))

>>> print (shellobject.SpecialFolders("Common AppData"))

>>> print (shellobject.SpecialFolders("AppData"))
F:\Documents and Settings\Randy1\Application Data
>>> print (shellobject.SpecialFolders("My Music"))

>>> print (shellobject.SpecialFolders("MyMusic"))

>>> print (shellobject.SpecialFolders("AppData"))
F:\Documents and Settings\Randy1\Application Data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN, [SpecialFolders Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe.aspx).

The following special folders are available:

- AllUsersDesktop
- AllUsersStartMenu
- AllUsersPrograms
- AllUsersStartup
- Desktop
- Favorites
- Fonts
- MyDocuments
- NetHood
- PrintHood
- Programs
- Recent
- SendTo
- StartMenu
- Startup
- Templates

Though it seems the above list is incomplete, e.g. AppData is also available. We can still conclude: some of special folders are not available.

We can experiment `WshShell` object in *Windows Script Host* which is more reliable than `win32com`.

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WScript.Echo(shell.SpecialFolders("ProgramFiles"));
WScript.Echo(shell.SpecialFolders("AppData"));
```

`shell.SpecialFolders("ProgramFiles")` is also an empty string.

Comment: Thank You!  I would vote for your answer, but I am so new to the site I don't have permission...

Comment: It seems the easiest way in windows to get this info is by typing shell:SpecialFolderName.  I was thinking this was passing it like that.  Your answer helped me understand what was going on better.