# platform-independent way to fetch pictures folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make some image manipulation software. On many popular operating systems there would be a default picture folder. For example:

```
Mac: /User/corvid/Pictures/
Ubuntu: /home/corvid/Pictures/
Windows: C:\\user\\corvid\\My Pictures
```

I know of a way to make it work for windows based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858851/python-get-windows-special-folders-for-currently-logged-in-user)

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
print shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_MYPICTURES, None, 0)
```

However, is there a way to make this a bit more generic? Is there a way to fetch the "Pictures" directory in a platform-independent way?

Comment: Are you sure it's "My Pictures" on Windows, not just "Pictures"?

Comment: it might be, was just using a possible example to show differences

Comment: On Vista and Windows 7 "Pictures" definitely works, so maybe wim's answer is just fine. Not sure about older versions.

Comment: on my mac os x yosemite it is `/Users/` not `/User/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on Mac, Linux, and Windows:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path.home() / "Pictures"
```

Comment: Use `os.path.sep` instead of `/`

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the "My" on windows... d'oh!

Comment: @wim It may be a mistake in the question itself ;0 - on my Vista it's "Pictures", and on another machine with Windows 7 also.

Comment: in contradiction to other systems on Linux the name could be different in different languages (MacOS and Windows make rename in the user interface). For example on my machine, it is `/home/useri/Obrazy`, where "Obrazy" is the translation of "Pictures" for Polish.

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import environ
import os.path

pictures = os.path.join(environ["USERPROFILE"], "Pictures")
```