# Command line with multiple arguments, variables and current working directory

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to call a command line with Popen.

The command line operates in the shell

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Inventor
Inventor -exe -- no-gui -f C:\Users\Vince\Documents\Inventor\Inventor.iam
```

But when I try this with Popen in my program

```
from subprocess import *
from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser("~")
path = home + "\\Documents\\Inventor\\Inventor.iam"
cmd = "Inventor -exe -- no-gui -f " + path
Popen(cmd, cwd="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Inventor")
```

It returns me `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]`

So I can't figure out what is wrong with the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add (shell =True) in argument

but use with caution
[warning for using shell = True argument](https:////docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

Comment: It doesn't work. It's better with \\ but I think the problem comes from the arguments `"Inventor -exe -- no-gui -f "`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the full path to the executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os.path
import subprocess

exedir = os.path.join(os.environ['PROGRAMFILES'], "Inventor")
exepath = os.path.join(exedir, "Inventor.exe")
filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), r'Documents\Inventor\Inventor.iam')
subprocess.check_call([exepath, '-exe', '--', 'no-gui', '-f', filepath],
                      cwd=exedir)
```

See [Popen with conflicting executable/path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789749/4279), to understand how the executable is search with and without `shell=True`.

To avoid hardcoding paths to special Windows folders, see [Python, get windows special folders for currently logged-in user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3858851/4279).