# Python - cannot "find" files with "getenv("APPDATA")"?

Tags: python

I am trying to locate/edit a file within AppData. This is what I am doing:

```
 if os.path.isfile(getenv("APPDATA") + "File"):
        print("Found file!")
```

I am then going to open that file

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(getenv("APPDATA") + "File")
```

However, it just creates a temp file called `RoamingFile` there. Eventhough my file is in the AppData directory. I have played around with permissions with no luck. I can also access it if I go straight to the path eg `C:\Users\user\AppData`.

I have hit a brick wall really because I have been trying to solve it/look for answers for hours. - Thanks

Comment: have you tried printing out what `getenv("APPDATA") + "File"` returns, to see if it is what you're assuming it is? That should be the very first step when debugging this problem.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Thanks, I will try.

Comment: @BittenFleax: I find it very offense that people call me rude for no reason. Don't be rude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the path separator.

The `%APPDATA%` variable usually points to `r'C:\User\username\AppData\Roaming'`. When you append `'File'` to this you get `r'C:\User\username\AppData\RoamingFile'`

Use `os.path.join()` to join paths:

```
filename = os.path.join(getenv("APPDATA"), "File")
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    print("Found file!")
```

Note that if you want to access `...\AppData\Local`, it is probably best to use the Win32 API function to retrieve its location. This either needs ctypes or e.g. the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32) module as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858851/python-get-windows-special-folders-for-currently-logged-in-user).

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
app_data_local = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, None, 0)
```

Comment: Hello @dhke, I've added this answer a while back too, could you tell me how I could address my answer better, since this looks like the same answer that I've given :-)

Comment: Ohhhhh right. I misunderstood the way it works completely. Thanks. If it goes to Roaming. How would you locate to AppData/Local then?

Comment: @ComputerFellow Classical case of concurrent edit. I wrote mine while you where still editing yours.

Comment: @dhke +1 haha, yup, feels a bit odd! :-)

Comment: @BittenFleax By asking Windows to hand it to you. Which requires an additional library or some fiddling around with ctypes, however.

Comment: @dhke Ah so it is difficult then?

Comment: @BittenFleax That depends on your notion of difficult. Windows has an API call for it, but that isn't exposed to Python code by any of the builtin modules. Hence `pywin32`.

Comment: @dhke Ah right okay. I did your method with win32com and worked fine. I had to to some tweaking with setup.py for py2exe to compile it correctly. But all works now! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You've missed a `"\\"`... and you should be using `os.path.join`:

```
filepath = os.path.join(os.getenv("APPDATA"), "File")
if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    # do something
```

Comment: Wow, such a small mistake. However, I still cannot open the sqlite file? Well, I can it just cannot find a table in it which I am 100% sure there is because I am viewing it.

Comment: @BittenFleax Are you viewing the correct file? Because from your question you seem to view a file in `C:\User\username\AppData\File`, but make a connection to `C:\User\username\AppData\Roaming\File`.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally editor your answer instead of mine. Rolled back. And time to stop working :)

Comment: @dhke Christmas is almost here :-)