# Create Shortcut returns error but worked fine in other computer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ran this on 5 computers, 4 worked fine but 1 returned an error
[image]

This is what my code looks like

```
desktop = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")
shortcutpath = os.path.join(desktop, 'MeetingAssistant.lnk')
target = path + '\\MeetingAssistant.exe'
icon = imagefolder + '\\icon.ico'

time.sleep(1)
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(shortcutpath)
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = path
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.IconLocation = icon
shortcut.save()
```

Comment: 80070003 is ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND.  Is it possible this user has his Desktop folder in another location?  Is his computer configured for another language?  There are APIs to fetch the actual name of the special folders, like Desktop.

Comment: @TimRoberts How do i find this desktop then

Comment: @TimRoberts There's no 80070003 in the picture?

Comment: -2147024893 is 0x80070003.  I don't know why PythonCom insists on printing the error numbers in decimal when all Windows COM errors are in hex.

Comment: The API is `win32com.shell.SHGetFolderPath`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858851/python-get-windows-special-folders-for-currently-logged-in-user